# Pandas DataFrame filtering based on second column

Tags: pandas, filter, dataframe

I have a Pandas Dataframe called `names` as follows:

```
name        status
A           X
B           Y
C           Z
D           X
```

I want to get the name column (e.g. `names['name']`), but only with names which do NOT have the status Y or Z.

So the result should be:

```
name        status
A           X
D           X
```

how can I do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [`isin`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.isin.html#pandas.Series.isin) to generate the boolean mask and negate it using `~`:

```
In [230]:
df[~df['status'].isin(['Y','Z'])]

Out[230]:
  name status
0    A      X
3    D      X
```

Result of `isin`:

```
In [231]:
df['status'].isin(['Y','Z'])

Out[231]:
0    False
1     True
2     True
3    False
Name: status, dtype: bool
```

You can then just access the 'name' column like so:

```
In [232]:
df.loc[~df['status'].isin(['Y','Z']),'name']

Out[232]:
0    A
3    D
Name: name, dtype: object
```

Answer (score 2):

This will also work:

```
df.loc[(df['status']!='Y') & (df['status']!='Z')]
```

Or, if you just want the data in the name column to be displayed:

```
df.loc[(df['status']!='Y') & (df['status']!='Z'), 'name']
```